# Wifi stuck in "Obtaining IP address", but connects in another area

Tags: wi-fi, networking

When I am at my desk at work the Wifi does not connect to my phone and I get stuck looping in "obtaining IP address". However if I step away from my desk to another part of the building, my phone connects no problem. I noticed that if I download a large file somewhere else and get back to my desk, my phone stays connected (although at a lower signal which is fine) until the download is finished, and then switches back to "obtaining IP address". This being a work environment I don't have access to any of the routers. Is there anyway I can force my phone to connect to the router in the other part of the building? thanks.

Some other notes. I am using a Oneplus 5. I have tried changing to a static IP, the same IP that works when my phone actually connects somewhere else in the building, but the phones says "connected, no internet".

Comment: It might just be a weak signal at your desk. Can you confirm that a different phone works at your desk? If not you might have to talk to IT at your company to have them take a look at it. Not sure if you can do anything phone side that will make a difference.

Comment: different phone does not work at my desk. IT cannot help as they are not responsible for personal devices...pretty sure they are lazy lol. Is there no way to stop the phone from automatically switching to the closest router?

Comment: Unfortunately, if another phone also doesn't work, that is a configuration issue of the network. Nothing you can do phone side. IT should care, it is their mess up.  As someone who has spent a lot of time doing networking I can tell you it wouldn't be that hard of a fix for them to move the router location a little, or even add another one due to poor coverage.